# Formatting a column with EPPLUS Excel Library

Tags: c#, export-to-excel, epplus, number-formatting

I wrote a C# program to create an excel spreadsheet.  The sheet has multiple columns.  I want to format ONE of the columns.

```
aFile = new FileInfo(excelDocName); // excelDocName is a string
ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(aFile);
var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Content");
ws.View.ShowGridLines = true;
ws.Cells["B:B"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0.00";
ws.Cells[1, 1].Value = "AA";
ws.Cells[1, 2].Value = "BB";
ws.Cells[1, 3].Value = "CC";
ws.Cells[1, 4].Value = "DD";
for (int row = 2; row <= 10; ++row)
  for (int col = 1; col <= 4; ++col)
  {
  ws.Cells[row, col].Value = row * col;
  }
ws.Row(1).Style.Font.Bold = true;
pck.Save();
```

The problem is, while it's formatting the column correct, it's also formatting other columns with the format and not just the column I specified.
I also tried:

```
ws.Column(1).Style.Numberformat.Format = "0.00";
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: hmm, I can't see anything wrong with the selectors. You are using a template right? Is it possible the template itself is formatted wrong? Or the format you are setting could be the default one for numbers ? Sorry Im not much of a help

Comment: I am not using a template. Did know I could use one.  I may look into that.thanks

Answer (score 16):

Are you opening an existing file?  It may have a format already applied to the other columns prior to you opening it.  Or a template like astian said.

Clear all the formatting just in case like this:

```
ws.Cells["A:D"].Style.Numberformat.Format = null;
ws.Cells["B:B"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0.00";
```

---

Full unit test in EPPlus 4.0.3:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Format_Single_Column_Test()
{
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28698226/formatting-a-column-with-epplus-excel-library
    var excelDocName = @"c:\temp\temp.xlsx";
    var aFile = new FileInfo(excelDocName); // excelDocName is a string

    if (aFile.Exists)
        aFile.Delete();

    ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(aFile);
    var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Content");
    ws.View.ShowGridLines = true;
    ws.Cells["A:D"].Style.Numberformat.Format = null;
    ws.Cells["B:B"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0.00";
    ws.Cells[1, 1].Value = "AA";
    ws.Cells[1, 2].Value = "BB";
    ws.Cells[1, 3].Value = "CC";
    ws.Cells[1, 4].Value = "DD";
    for (int row = 2; row <= 10; ++row)
        for (int col = 1; col <= 4; ++col)
        {
            ws.Cells[row, col].Value = row*col;
        }
    ws.Row(1).Style.Font.Bold = true;
    pck.Save();
}
```

Comment: I am creating the spreadsheet from scratch without a template. It turns out it is sufficient for me to format only a few of the columns.  I don't like it, because I still don't understand why except that this might be a bug.  I'm not going to play with it now that it's working.  Still I'm going to keep this int in mind, that I can set the format to null. Thanks

Comment: @elbillaf  What version of EPPlus are you running?  I tried the added unit test above in version 4.0.3.

Comment: @elbillaf Are you able to run the unit test above?  Or can you test your code on a different machine?  Could it be your default excel template for new documents has been changed? http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-excel/excel-2013-change-default-template/6c6387d0-211c-4f6e-a856-3501324d5098