# How to set CSS style in EPPLus?

Tags: c#, css, datatable, epplus

I'm generating Excel from DataTable using EPPlus library.

I'm modifying the code that used to loop through datatable and create spreadsheet.

That code used to set the style for the cell with the following code:

```
td.Attributes.Add("style", @"mso-number-format:\@");
```

I have the following piece of logic:

```
for (int row = 6; row <= totalRow; row++)
{
    for (int col = 1; col <= 9; col++)
    {
        string colVol = (string)ws.Cells[row, col].Value;
        bool isNumeric = long.TryParse(colVol, out n);
        if (isNumeric && colVol.Length > 10)
        {
           ws.Cells[row, col] //need to assign css style here

        }
    }
}
```

I need to do the same using EPPlus.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

To set the background color of a cell simply use the following code:

```
ws.Cells[row, col].Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
ws.Cells[row, col].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Red);
```

In order to set anything relating to the Fill property you must specify the PatternType that is going to be used to actually fill the cell

EPPlus allows for a much wider array of formatting options but those go beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: I need to set styles and attribute like in the example I provided

Comment: @gene Could you please provide more information? For instance, what is 'dt'? I answered based on what I could infer you wanted. If you provide more information on what it is exactly you are trying to accomplish I will gladly edit my answer :)

Comment: `td` is a table cell. I need to set an css style for the cell's value as I showed in example

Comment: @gene Ok. What object does the table cell property come from?

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is the link to my post I submitted before with the full code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36017247/how-to-get-a-value-from-excel-spreadsheet-cell-using-epplus

Comment: @gene Did Ernie not answer the question your'e asking or are you saying you just need to know how to apply styles in general? Also, when you say CSS style do you literally mean CSS (HTML cell) or do you mean just excel cell formatting?

Comment: No, that approach did not work for me. I need to apply CSS styling to the table cell that is created if that cell has a number with more then 10 characters. I need to replicate something like this: `td.Attributes.Add("style", @"mso-number-format:\@");`

Comment: @gene When you say table cell, do you mean an excel worksheet cell?